# Multiuser System in Kotlin with admin grants

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I want to implement a multiuser system in my app with admin users and no admin users. An admin user can see some features on the screen that other users can't. I'm trying to do it with Jetpack Compose and Firebase auth/Firestore, I use a UserData data class with some variables and one of them is "role", here I put the user role: "USER" or "ADMIN". I don't know if this is the best option to implement, recommendations are welcome. What I'm doing here is adding a FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener in my use repo, when it changes, if the user is not null I check in Firebase the role and return true or false, if the user is null I return false.

CODE)

```
override fun getUserRole(viewModelScope: CoroutineScope) = callbackFlow {
    val authStateListener = FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener { auth ->
        auth.currentUser?.uid?.let {
            usersRef.document(it).get().addOnSuccessListener { document ->
                if (document != null) {
                    val userRole = document.get("role").toString() == "ADMIN"
                    trySend(userRole)
                }
            }
        } ?: trySend(false)
    }
    auth.addAuthStateListener(authStateListener)
    awaitClose {
        auth.removeAuthStateListener(authStateListener)
    }
}.stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(), false)
```

I don't know how to implement a multiuser system, and I tried this, need help doing this.

Another spec I want to implement is to get userData from Firestore and I will need the data in all the apps, but I don't want to check to auth.currentUser (if is null or not..) in every ViewModel and get data in every ViewModeldepending of user state. What can I do about it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to track the auth state, then indeed you have to use an [AuthStateListener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener). Such a listener fires each time the auth state of the user changes. To check if a user is authenticated or not, then you have to call [FirebaseAuth#getCurrentUser()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth#getCurrentUser()):

> Returns the currently signed-in FirebaseUser or null if there is none.

This means that you only have to check the result against nullity:

```
val authStateListener = AuthStateListener { auth ->
    trySend(auth.currentUser == null)
}
```

So your entire `getUserRole` function should look like this:

```
override fun getUserRole(viewModelScope: CoroutineScope) = callbackFlow {
    val authStateListener = AuthStateListener { auth ->
        trySend(auth.currentUser == null) //
    }
    auth.addAuthStateListener(authStateListener)
    awaitClose {
        auth.removeAuthStateListener(authStateListener)
    }
}.stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(), auth.currentUser == null)
//
```

Now, if you want to check a field in Firestore and take some action based on the existing value, then you have to perform a separate operation. So in the place where you handle the result of the above method, when you collect the result and you get `true`, meaning that the user is authenticated, then right after that you have to perform the Firestore call. According to the result you get from Firestore, you can then take further action.

You're getting wrong results when using your actual code, because you're assuming that the user is authenticated when the document you're checking exists and the value of the `role` value is equal to ADMIN, which is a wrong approach, hence the wrong results.

To simplify some things, please note that the [DocumentSnapshot#get(field: String)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot#get(java.lang.String)) function returns an object of type [Any](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-any/). Calling `toString()` on such an object will indeed return the value of the field. However, if you already know that the `role` field holds a string, then you should consider calling the [DocumentSnapshot#getString(field: String)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot#getString(java.lang.String)) function which:

> Returns the value of the field as a String.

So in your use case, the code can be simplified to:

```
val userRole = document.getString("role") == "ADMIN"
```

Comment: Thanks for response Alex, I always take a look to your repos and try to follow your implementations :). About this, yes, I have this code to get auth state in my app but I want to check user role when the auth state changes. Maybe better solution is to collectLatest auth state in a MAIN viewmodel, and if it is true, getUserRole and UserData and save responses in a flow, and if it is false reset the flows? And then use this viewmodel in all my screens? Thanks!

Comment: It might work. Never tried that, but you can give it a try and see if it works.

Comment: Yes, It helped me to get role. Now I’ve tried what I said, but the code inside collectLatest when collecting auth state is executing more than once.. Is there any solution?

Comment: There is no other solution I'm aware of.